# Windows Store app's overriden resource value ignored in template

Tags: xaml, templates, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm creating a Windows Store app where each page has a dominant color used for titles, buttons and such.

In `App.xaml` I've created a default `Brush` that's overriden in each `Page`'s xaml file, and a style template for `Button`s which I reuse in every page. The templates are supposed to use the page's color but for some reason they stick with the default value.

Here are my xaml files.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application
    x:Class="Foo.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Foo"
    RequestedTheme="Light">

  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary>
          <SolidColorBrush x:Name="SectionDefaultBrush" Color="Red" />
          <Style TargetType="Button" x:Name="NavigationButtonStyle">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Myriad Pro" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                  <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Border" Fill="#f4f4f4" Margin="0" />
                    <TextBlock Foreground="{ ThemeResource SectionDefaultBrush }"  Text=">" FontSize="31" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#5A5A5A" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="31"/>
                  </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
          </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**SomePage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="Foo.Pages.SomePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

  <Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SectionDefaultBrush" Color="Green" />
  </Page.Resources>

  <ViewBox>
    <Canvas>
      <TextBlock Text="Some text" Foreground="{ ThemeResource SectionDefaultBrush }" Canvas.Left="130" TextWrapping="Wrap" Canvas.Top="252" Height="177" Width="507" FontFamily="Myriad Pro"  FontSize="54" />
      <Button Content="Click me" Style="{ ThemeResource NavigationButtonStyle }" Canvas.Left="130" Canvas.Top="900" Width="507" Height="48" />
    </Canvas>
  <ViewBox>
```

In this example, the `TextBlock`'s text color is green as expected (and red if I remove the `Brush` from `Page.Resources`), but the `Button`'s content remains red. Is there a way to tell the template to use the final color ?

Comment: Have you tried using StaticResource?

Comment: In the template? Yes, but it gives the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app's resource dictionary doesn't know about other dictionaries and unlike with WPF's `DynamicResources` - `StaticResource` isn't reevaluated and `ThemeResource` is, but I think only when the actual theme changes. The way you can customize the color of that button is to use `TemplateBinding` in the template and bind to say the `Foreground` property of the button and also set that in the `Foreground` `Setter` of your button style to `{StaticResource SectionDefaultBrush}`. Then in your page you can override that by setting the `Foreground` of the button to a different value or using a derived button style that changes the `Foreground` value.

Ideally too - you should define theme resources in your dictionary so the brushes change depending on OS theme (especially high contrast). You might want to name your brush then as "SectionDefaultThemeBrush" instead of just "SectionDefaultBrush".

Comment: That worked, thanks. Although it feels kinda hacky as we're using a property that happens to be unused in this case (the `Buttons`'s `Foreground`)... How could I do if I needed it to be set to something else ?

Comment: You also have the `Background`. :) Otherwise you have a few options. The ugly solution is to also use `Tag` which is a general purpose property that you can use for anything, but that shouldn't be used for anything other than prototyping. Otherwise you can define an attached property or subclass `Button` and add your own properties.

Comment: Oh and then again - you can do everything in XAML - just define multiple styles and switch styles based on location to customize as many brushes as you want. Typically though controls don't have more than 2-3 colors and if you really need more - these should be common brush resources reused everywhere in the app.